# Keeping Track of session in a command line application

Tags: c++, session, boost, environment

How do I keep track of session for different users in the command line application.One way I figured out is to store the sessionId sent by the server into the environment variables.Second is to maintain a file having the sessionId returned by server after successful login and to encrypt it.

I have implemented the second solution but it is quite complex when multiple sessions are in use.

Is there any way to implement the first apart from setenv and putenv that is more consistent on windows and linux both platforms ?

Technology/Library in use are C++ along with boost

Comment: Storing user data in files in $HOME/.application_name/  is a common approach

Comment: Command-line programs aren't typically session-based, therefore there really exists no good framework for handling these things. If a command-line application needs a "session" it typically never ends until the "session" is over. Temporary files is probably the best bet when it comes to portability.